# selecting anchor elements with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector

I want to select the menu-enabled anchor with javascript, which is a small image and when I click it it should change a class of the background to highlight the menu. 
The change class works, I tried document.onclick and it works, but when I try to be specific wrapper>nav> a.menu-enabled it doesn't select it.
I've tried:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('nav'); 
var anchor = menu.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

to be able to click on every link just to test, but it didn't work.

I've tried:

```
var anchor = menu.getElementsByClassName('menu-enabled');
```

and then

```
anchor.onclick...` but still no result :(
```

tried using jquery
   `$("a.menu-enabled").onclick = function()` 
but still no result

Currently is set to click anywhere on the document until I get it done.

```
    <script>
    document.onclick = function() {
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("overlay-show");
    } 
    </script>


<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">Tro</a>
            </div>
        <nav id="nav" class="menu-icon">
                <a class="menu-enabled">&nbsp;</a>
                <a class="link-enabled" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
                <a class="prev-disabled">&nbsp;</a>
                <a class="next-disabled">&nbsp;</a>
                <a class="back-disabled">&nbsp;</a>
            </nav>
            <div class="overlay">
        <nav class="meniu">
                <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#2">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#3">Link 3/a>
                <a href="#4">Link 4</a>
            </nav>
```

Edit 1: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bFXZj/

Edit 2: Ok, I think the problem is I could not click the button, tried it on something else and it worked, I thinkg the z-index is the problem, gonna return with an answer soon.

Edit 3: it could be because I gave the anchor a background?

```css
nav.menu-icon a.menu-enabled{
    background: url(http://www.xxx.xx/menu.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: create fiddle please..?

Comment: Read up on [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node), [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) and [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/); learn about the differences. Then try again and see if you can get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a.menu-enabled', function(e){
        // Do something
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery version would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.menu-enabled').click(function(e){
        // Do something
    });
});
```

Rather than `$("a.menu-enabled").onclick = function()`

**Edit:**

Updated your jsFiddle and it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/bFXZj/1/

Comment: Try ensuring the z-index of not only the link, but its ancestors is higher than any siblings.  Are you able to select text in the link?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in the console?  It could be css related but it seems unlikely as selecting the text proves that the click even is hitting that element.

Comment: ok, it works now, had to clear cache and add some z-index lines. Ty all